# Hadoop MapReduce without cluster - is it possible?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to run a Hadoop MapReduce program without a cluster? I mean, I am just trying to fiddle around a little with map/reduce, for educational purposes, so all I want is to run few MapReduce programs on my computer, I don't need any job splitting to multiple nodes etc... Don't need any performance boosts or anything, as I said, just for educational purposes.. Do I still need to run a VM to achieve this? I am using IntelliJ Ultimate, and I'm trying to run simple WordCount.. I believe I've set up all necessary libraries and the entire project, and upon running I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster.
Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
```

I've found some posts saying that the entire map/reduce process can be run locally on the jvm, but couldn't yet find the way how to do it.

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole installation tutorial of "pseudo-distributed" mode specifically walks you through the installation of a single node Hadoop cluster

There's also [the "Mini cluster"](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html) which you'll find some Hadoop projects use for unit&integration tests

I feel like you're just asking if you need HDFS or YARN, though, and the answer is no, Hadoop can read `file://` prefixed file paths from disk, with or without a cluster

Keep in mind that splitting is not just between nodes, but also between multiple cores of a single computer. If you're not doing any parallel processing, there's not much reason to use Hadoop other than to learn the API semantics.

<sub>Aside: From an "educational perspective", in my career thus far, I find more people writing Spark than MapReduce, and not many jobs asking specifically for MapReduce code</sub>